# Having issues with the fscanf function in C

Tags: c, scanf

So, inspired from the file pointers, I want to create my own "grocery store". Here I want to scan the prices of my products, but I keep getting a segmentation fault

```
int main(void)
{
FILE* fuf; 
fuf = fopen("apranqner.csv", "r");

printf("Price: ");

int price[15];

/*  I only want to print the first row of the table  

    3800.0, Butter-, Dairy Farm, 55
    500.0, Milk-, Dairy Farm, 60
    600.0, Tan-, Dairy Farm, 11
    450.0, Matsoon-, Dairy Farm, 6
    550.0, SourCream-, Dairy Farm, 8
    2800.0, Cheese-, Dairy Farm, 7
    250.0, Bread-, Bakery Goods, 45
    400.0, Cake-, Bakery Goods, 5
    700.0, Pringles-, Bakery Goods, 10
    100.0, Apache-, Bakery Goods, 11
    400.0, Coca-Cola-, Beverage Island, 12
    400.0, Pepsi-, Beverage Island, 12
    400.0, Fanta-, Beverage Island, 1
    250.0, Jermuk-, Beverage Island, 4
    100.0, 
*/

while (fscanf(fuf, "Price: %f ", price) != EOF)
{
    printf("%f", *price);
}   

fclose(fuf);
}
```

Comment: `price` is an array of `int`, but you're `fscanf` format specifier states `float`.

Comment: That's not the only thing that's wrong.  If you want to fill that array, you're going  to need an array index that increments for each item.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I switched it to float. My program still won't work

Comment: Like I said, that's not the only thing that's wrong.

Comment: You should probably read [How to Debug Small Programs.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You also need to learn how fscanf works and how arrays work.

Comment: Instead of using fscanf, you could also use [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok), [`strtof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) and [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol).

Comment: If you only want to print the first row, why are you calling `fscanf()` in a loop?

Comment: `fscanf` does not go looking for the request items anywhere in the input. It only matches things from the format string with the very next things in the input. If the format string has “Price:”, then the input has to have “Price:” too, or matching stops. If the format string has “%f”, then the input **at the current point of reading** has to have text that looks like a floating-point numeral, or matching stops. To process the input you show, you have to write more code to examine the input and skip the parts you do not want.

Comment: It is unsafe to use the result of `scanf` or `fscanf` without first checking that the return value of that function has the desired value (in your case 1). It is not sufficient to only check for `EOF`. See this link for further information: [A beginner's guide away from `scanf`](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use `fscanf` here is a possible solution. Note that you have to use special string matching syntax to be able to scan character strings because strings have non alphabetic characters like `-` or spaces:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  FILE* fuf; 
  float val1;
  char desc1[20];
  char desc2[20];
  int val2;
  int rc;

  fuf = fopen("apranqner.csv", "r");
  if (fuf == NULL)
  {
        perror("fopen");
        return 1;
  }

  rc = fscanf(fuf, "%f, %[A-Za-z-], %[A-Za-z ], %d ", &val1, desc1, desc2, &val2) ;
  if (rc == 4)
  {
    printf("First row\n");
    printf("field 1: %f \n", val1);
    printf("field 2: %s \n", desc1);
    printf("field 3: %s \n", desc2);
    printf("field 4: %d \n", val2);
  }  
  else
  {
    printf("Error: only %d tokens scanned\n", rc);
    return 1;
  } 

  fclose(fuf);
  return 0;
}
```

Execution:

```
cat apranqner.csv 
3800.0, Butter-, Dairy Farm, 55
./fscanf
First row
field 1: 3800.000000 
field 2: Butter- 
field 3: Dairy Farm 
field 4: 55
```

Here is another version of the code to work with a structure stored in array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX     1
#define LENGTH  20

int main(void)
{

  typedef struct {
    float price;
    char* product;
    char* department;
    int stock;
  } pro;


  FILE* fuf;
  pro menu[MAX];
  int rc;

  fuf = fopen("apranqner.csv", "r");
  if (fuf == NULL)
  {
        perror("fopen");
        return 1;
  }

  menu[0].product = malloc(LENGTH * sizeof (char));
  if (menu[0].product == NULL)
  {
        perror("malloc");
        return 1;
  }
  menu[0].department = malloc(LENGTH * sizeof (char));
  if (menu[0].department == NULL)
  {
        perror("malloc");
        return 1;
  }

  rc = fscanf(fuf, "%f, %[A-Za-z-], %[A-Za-z ], %d ",
                   &menu[0].price,
                   menu[0].product,
                   menu[0].department,
                   &menu[0].stock);

  if (rc == 4)
  {
    printf("First row\n");
    printf("price: %f \n", menu[0].price);
    printf("product: %s \n", menu[0].product);
    printf("dept. : %s \n", menu[0].department);
    printf("stock: %d \n", menu[0].stock);
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Error: only %d tokens scanned\n", rc);
    return 1;
  }

  fclose(fuf);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: I used a for loop and now I can actually print everything  in the text file!

I also tried storing them in an array that has a predefined type:

typedef struct
{
    float price;
    char* product;
    char* department;
    int stock;
} 
pro;
However, it only stores the int and float values. 

            pro menu[MAX]; 
            for loop...
            menu[o].price = val1;
            menu[o].stock = val2;
            strcpy(menu[o].product, desc1);
            strcpy(menu[o].department, desc2);
I tried assigning the values, but in that case every element is the same

Comment: I added a new program in my answer that works with a structure stored in a single item array:  if you use `char *` in your structure you must call `malloc` to allocate memory.